# Convert PublishRelay to BehaviorRelay of optional Element

Tags: rx-swift

I have the following code in RxSwift 4.0-based project:

```
private var _myRelay = PublishRelay<MyData>()

var myRelay: Observable<MyData> {

    return _myRelay.asObservable()
}
```

Now I need to keep the last value (if any) in `_myRelay`, so I decided to convert it to `BehaviorRelay`:

```
private var _myRelay = BehaviorRelay<MyData?>(value: nil)
```

I want to keep public interface intact

```
var myRelay: Observable<MyData>
```

I mean I do not want to convert it to

```
var myRelay: Observable<MyData?>
```

The idea is not to "publish" initial value == `nil` to subscribers of `myRelay`, and start publishing only after some data appears. How can I do it? I am completely beginner in Rx, but I am sure there should be some elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to filter out the nils. If you were using 5.0 then you would do that with `compactMap` but since you said 4.0 that means you will need a filter and map:

```
var myRelay: Observable<MyData> {

    return _myRelay.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }.asObservable()
}
```

but you might actually be better off using a `ReplaySubject` instead of a Relay.

```
private let _myRelay = ReplaySubject<MyData>.create(bufferSize: 1)

var myRelay: Observable<MyData> {

    return _myRelay.asObservable()
}
```

That way, you don't have to deal with nils at all. (Also note, `_myRelay` should be a `let` not a var.)

Doing the above will also allow you to emit a `completed` event when the observable goes out of scope (a relay doesn't allow that.)

```
private let _myRelay = ReplaySubject<MyData>.create(bufferSize: 1)

var myRelay: Observable<MyData> {
    return _myRelay.asObservable()
}

deinit {
    _myRelay.onCompleted()
}
```